Timeout Errors in Jupiter API
In my code made it with Node js
const executeSwap = async (quote, telegramId) => {
try {
    logger.info('Starting executeSwap function');

    const wallet = await getWallet(telegramId);
    const connection = getConnection();

    if (!wallet || !connection) {
        throw new Error('Wallet or connection not initialized');
    }

    // Fetch the latest blockhash
    logger.info('Fetching latest blockhash');
    const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');

    // Prepare swap request data
    const swapRequestData = {
        quoteResponse: quote,
        userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
        wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
        computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: 3000000, // Adjust based on priority
        computeUnitsLimit: 2368431, // Adjust based on priority
        slippageBps: 50
    };

    const response = await axios.post(`${JUPITER_API_ENDPOINT}/swap`, swapRequestData);

    const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(response.data.swapTransaction, 'base64');
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

    // Assign the latest blockhash
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

    // Sign the transaction
    transaction.sign([wallet]);

;
const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
skipPreflight: false,
preflightCommitment: 'finalized',
maxRetries: 3,
});
    logger.info(`Transaction sent with ID: ${txid}`);

    // Poll for confirmation
    logger.info('Polling for transaction confirmation');
    const confirmation = await pollTransactionConfirmation(connection, txid, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds timeout

    if (confirmation.value.err) {
        logger.error(`Transaction failed: ${confirmation.value.err}`);
        throw new Error(`Transaction failed: ${confirmation.value.err}`);
    }

    logger.info('Transaction confirmed successfully');

    return {
        success: true,
        txid,
        explorerUrl: `${SOLANA_EXPLORER}/${txid}`
    };

} catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Swap execution error: ${error.message}`);

    if (error.message.includes('insufficient lamports') || error.message.includes('Insufficient SOL')) {
        throw new Error('Insufficient SOL balance for transaction fees');
    } else if (error.message.includes('block height exceeded') || error.message.includes('Signature')) {
        throw new Error('Transaction signature expired. Please try again.');
    }

    throw error;
}

};
const pollTransactionConfirmation = async (connection, txid, timeout) => {
const startTime = Date.now();
const interval = 5000; // 2 seconds
while (Date.now() - startTime < timeout) {
const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(txid, 'finalized');
    if (confirmation.value || confirmation) {
        return confirmation;
    }

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
}

throw new Error('Transaction confirmation timeout');

};
I keep getting this errors
2024-11-25 11:40:46 [ERROR]: Swap execution error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.00 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 4YkduMMzW4dYf3XqLpvGznqHfiKqGUznfSivEyRVJXByXgDNYS3crD7Gvrtryz1p1CjbVK51h8gMjUfmJaHRwucQ using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.

2024-11-25 11:40:46 [ERROR]: Swap execution error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.00 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 4YkduMMzW4dYf3XqLpvGznqHfiKqGUznfSivEyRVJXByXgDNYS3crD7Gvrtryz1p1CjbVK51h8gMjUfmJaHRwucQ using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.
I don't know how to solve it and prevent it to make the swaps properly
I tried different approaches
but keep giving me those errors, The main problem is That I gt many timeout errors a lot just 1 of 10 Transaction pass the rest fails and the other approach dont work as well, Im using Solana/web3.js, axios and Node js in a Telegram BOT
const { PublicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, VersionedTransaction, Connection } = require('@solana/web3.js');

const axios = require('axios');
const SOLANA_EXPLORER = 'https://solscan.io/tx';
const JUPITER_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v4/quote'; // Replace with actual Jupiter API endpoint
const executeSwap = async (quote, telegramId) => {
try {
logger.info('Starting executeSwap function');
    const wallet = await getWallet(telegramId);
    const connection = getConnection();

    if (!wallet || !connection) {
        throw new Error('Wallet or connection not initialized');
    }

    // Fetch the latest blockhash
    logger.info('Fetching latest blockhash');
    const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');

    // Prepare swap request data
    const swapRequestData = {
        quoteResponse: quote,
        userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
        wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
        computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: 3000000, // Adjust based on priority
        computeUnitsLimit: 2368431, // Adjust based on priority
        slippageBps: 50
    };

    logger.info('Requesting swap transaction from Jupiter API');
    const response = await axios.post(`${JUPITER_API_ENDPOINT}/swap`, swapRequestData);
    logger.info('Received swap transaction data from Jupiter');

    const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(response.data.swapTransaction, 'base64');
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);


    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;


    logger.info('Signing transaction');
    transaction.sign([wallet]);


    const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();


    logger.info('Sending raw transaction');
    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
        skipPreflight: false,
        preflightCommitment: 'finalized',
        maxRetries: 3,
    });

    logger.info(`Transaction sent with ID: ${txid}`);

    // Poll for confirmation
    const confirmation = await pollTransactionConfirmation(connection, txid, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds timeout

    if (confirmation.value.err) {
        throw new Error(`Transaction failed: ${confirmation.value.err}`);
    }

    logger.info('Transaction confirmed successfully');

    return {
        success: true,
        txid,
        explorerUrl: `${SOLANA_EXPLORER}/${txid}`
    };

} catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Swap execution error: ${error.message}`);

    if (error.message.includes('insufficient lamports') || error.message.includes('Insufficient SOL')) {
        throw new Error('Insufficient SOL balance for transaction fees');
    } else if (error.message.includes('block height exceeded') || error.message.includes('Signature')) {
        throw new Error('Transaction signature expired. Please try again.');
    }

    throw error;
}

};
const pollTransactionConfirmation = async (connection, txid, timeout) => {
const startTime = Date.now();
const interval = 2000; // 2 seconds
while (Date.now() - startTime < timeout) {
const status = await connection.getSignatureStatus(txid, {
searchTransactionHistory: true,
});
    if (status && status.value) {
        return status;
    }

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
}

throw new Error('Transaction confirmation timeout');

};
